# How to take accepted comments for a users which specific reputation

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

Using SEDE how is it possible to receive for Stack Overflow users all comments (timestap, text, etc.) who have reputation score greater than 100000?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "accepted" comment. Do you mean answers?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible, at least not in one go.

SEDE returns at most [50,000 rows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100) and even if I tune [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1185628) to limit to users with a reputation > 1,000,000 you should expect 82,130 records.

Download the [StackOverflow-comments.7z](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Comments.7z) and [StackOverflow-Users.7z](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Users.7z) from [Archive.Org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and do the join and selection on your local machine. Be aware that the Comments file is over 4 Giga byte. You don't want to fetch that data over your mobile data connection.

The Datadump is refreshed quarterly.

Comment: Nah fam, I got unlimited mobile data. But I don’t have 7-Zip on my phone, so I guess I’m still out of luck.